# Spring MVC Controller as Liferay Portlet and Servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, liferay, portlet

We are trying to have a spring MVC Controller that works as a portlet **and** a servlet, in order to be deployed in a Liferay context or as a standalone version. But it seems that the we have a conflict if we decide to have multiple RequestMappings on the method level (as opposed to having just 1 mapping on the level of the controller). we get the error shown below.

Note that if we decide to just have a requestMapping on the level of the controller that hosts a servlet mapping **and** a portlet mapping, it works.

```
@RequestMapping({"view", "/"})
```

The controller that does not work:

```
@Controller("controller")
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class MyController {

    @RenderMapping
    public ModelAndView doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) throws Exception {

         HttpServletRequest portletHttpReq = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request);
         HttpServletResponse portletHttpResp = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(response);
         return doView(portletHttpReq, portletHttpResp);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/home")
    protected ModelAndView doView(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
        // do something
        return new ModelAndView("view");
    }
}
```

The resulting error:

[...]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mode mappings conflict between method and type level: [/home] versus [view]

Do you have any suggestions on how we could implement such thing? What we would really like to avoid is having to maintain 2 controllers for every portlet/servlet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really think this is a good idea... the `@RequestMapping` annotation on the class level is going to cause problems for sure, simply because Spring portlet MVC expects the portlet mode, while Spring Web MVC expects a root URL.

Also, your code doesn't seem to be correct either, since `ModelAndView` exists in both the [portlet MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/ModelAndView.html) as the [web MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html) part of the Spring framework, and since you cannot import both, you'll have to specify the full package for one of them, and since you're not doing that either, your code is just wrong.

Except the technical issues, both portlets and servlet have different terminology and point of views. These are some key questions that pop up with me if I hear this:

- What are you going to do about the different phases (ACTION and RENDER)
- What about the the different portlet modes (VIEW, EDIT, HELP, ...)
- What are you going to do about the specific portlet features (PortletSession, PortletPreferences, ...)
- How are you going to handle the different kind of requests (ResourceRequest, ActionRequest, RenderRequest, PortletRequst, EventRequest vs HttpServletRequest)
- How are you going to handle security? The portal container provides authentication for you, a standalone web application does not.

And these are just questions from a portlet mindset, I'm pretty sure there are also technical issues if you look at it from the web application point of view.

It makes much more sense to divide your code into a view layer and business logic. Put the business logic in a separate package or separate services, and build a separate portlet- and standalone application, using the same/shared business logic.

Comment: thx for your reply g00. i have the same worries as yours, i was just wondering if anyone has a solution for this; what you are actually suggesting is that i have 2 controllers for servlet/portlet, the thing i was trying to avoid at the first place. let me just wait a few days before accepting your comment as an answer.